# http works but https is not working with docker

Tags: docker, apache, ssl

I am trying to host my application in angular from docker container. Its working fine with http but not working with https.

```
1. Created a signed ssl certificate in wsl and generated the .key and .crt files

2. Added the below code to docker file in the application
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Add the source code to app
COPY ./ /app/

# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install

ARG configuration=prod

RUN npm run build:$configuration

FROM httpd:2.4

COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/<appname>/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

3. Created an image using the command: docker build --build-arg configuration=dev . -t <image name>

4. To run the web traffic over ssl used the command for mounting
docker run -p 8235:80 -p 443:443 -v /mnt/c/usr/name/Azure/certificate.crt:/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt -v /mnt/c/usr/name/Azure/certificate.key:/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key <image name>

5. Uncommented the below lines in httpd.conf file present in /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

#LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

6. Also added the line  ServerName localhost   in httpd.conf
```

When tried browsing with http://localhost:8235/ it works fine but when using https://localhost:8235/ it does not work

The logs show the below result:
[Fri Feb 04 10:59:21.854978 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1:tid ##########] AH01906: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Feb 04 10:59:21.855031 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1:tid ##########] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Feb 04 10:59:21.856743 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid ##########] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 04 10:59:21.856787 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid ##########] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Is the server running HTTP and HTTPS on the same port? You only mention connecting to 8535, check if that is the forward for 443 in your case.

Comment: @JustLudo In docker run command I am using "docker run -p 8235:80 -p 443:443". Do I need to run http and https in different ports. I did not get how I can check "check if that is the forward for 443 in your case.". I am following this link https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Httpd will not run http and https protocols on the same port.
As it seems, it is configured to operate on port 80 (http) and port 443 (https). You configured port forwarding as

- 8235 -> 80 (http)
- 443 -> 443 (https)

so you need to test the URLs

```
http://localhost:8235/
https://localhost:443/
```

Depending on the certificate you provided the client may warn about an unsafe connection.

Comment: Thanks @Hiran Chaudhuri. This worked in my local machine wsl2 distro. When I try the same in Ubuntu machine on Azure server that is not working for even http. I am trying out some option. Will update the same.

Comment: I checked through again and the https worked in Ubuntu machine on Azure Server, but it is not working for http. In the httpd.conf file instead of  ServerName localhost I added ServerName <IP address>.